# How do I host my ASP.NET localhost website through a tunnel to a public URL without timeouts for free?

Tags: asp.net, url, localhost, hosting, tunnel

I'm integrating the HelloSign eSignature API into my ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2015. I am required to enter a domain/callback URL when creating a test app (https://app.hellosign.com/api/documentation).

I used Ngrok for my test app and got everything working, however, I need to consistently generate a new callback link and I would have to change all the links in the HelloSign app settings as well.

Are there any alternatives that I can use to tunnel my localhost (with port number) to a public URL permanently without paying?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get Dynamic DNS set up. This one Free DNS might do the trick. Take a look and let me know.

[https://freedns.afraid.org/]

To keep the local application going, you can build a C#.NET windows service to run the command in the background. This way it would automatically restart at reboot of the system.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the link! I've tried it out but sadly it does not work with localhost:<port number>.

Comment: Localhost? Hm, what if you specify your actual machine DNS name? Or maybe the IP Address? Then in your HOSTS file indicate your IP is localhost?

Comment: @BryanArtic Of course it doesn't work with localhost. Nothing will work with localhost, because localhost is specific to each machine. All that DNS does is map a domain name to an IP address. So you need to know your IP address in order to get DNS configured. Dynamic DNS has tools that can keep the IP address updated for your DNS in the event that you don't have a static IP.

Comment: Mason is right Bryan, you really need to specify the IP Address of the machine. You might also be running into an issue with the firewall allowing access on a specific port; just putting that out there so you can head that off at the pass.

Comment: Bryan, here are a list of services (Paid/Free) that should do what you are trying to. Let me know if any of the services on the list are helpful. https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/

Comment: @bbcompent1 Good afternoon! I've looked into the link and tried out the free ones, the services meet my requirements but I would have to keep running the command to link my localhost<port number> to their public URL. That's the issue here.

Comment: You might be able to wire up some C#.NET windows service to run the command in the background. This way it would automatically restart at reboot of the system.